# 'undefined control sequence' in beamer

Tags: beamer, errors

Can you please check out the following code for me?

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\mode<beamer>{%
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
}
\title{\textbf{MAGNETOHYDRODYNAMIC POISEUILLE FLOW OF VISCOUS FLUID WITH VARIABLE VISCOSITY IN A POROUS MEDIUM}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\titlepage
\color{magenta}
\begin{center}Department of  Mathematical Sciences,\\The Federal University of Technology,  Akure, Ondo State, Nigeria.\\By\end{center}
\begin{center}
{{\textbf{AFOLABI, FATIMO OPEYEMI}}\\}
{{\textbf{MTS/09/8362}}\\}
\end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Error messages are:

> Undefined control sequence. \trans@languagepath ->\languagename ,English l.363 \end{frame} The control sequence at the end of the top line of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have misspelled it (e.g., \hobx'), type I' and the correct spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue, and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
>
> Overfull \hbox (213.82292pt too wide) has occurred while \output is active [][][][] [] ! Undefined control sequence. \trans@languagepath ->\languagename ,English l.363 \end{frame} The control sequence at the end of the top line of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have misspelled it (e.g., \hobx'), type I' and the correct spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue, and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
>
> l.6 \begin{document} The control sequence at the end of the top line of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have misspelled it (e.g., \hobx'), type I' and the correct spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue, and I'll forget about whatever was undefined. ! Undefined control sequence. \trans@languagepath ->\languagename ,English
>
> l.15 \end{frame} The control sequence at the end of the top line of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have misspelled it (e.g., \hobx'), type I' and the correct spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue, and I'll forget about whatever was undefined. Overfull \vbox (13.1543pt too high) detected at line 15 [] Overfull \hbox (213.82292pt too wide) has occurred while \output is active [][][][] [] ! Undefined control sequence. \trans@languagepath ->\languagename ,English

Comment: How check out your code if we don't know what you want? What is your problem? be more specific

Comment: Example compiles just fine

Comment: @johnson but you should have an error message `;-)`

Comment: When I compile your code I don't get any undefined control sequnce error messages. Did you forget to add something to your example? You may also show your main `.aux` too, to see the versions you are using.

Comment: I don't know how to add the file for you.

Comment: here is the version am using:   TeXstudio 2.6.2 (SVN 4110M)
Using Qt Version 4.8.5, compiled with Qt 4.8.5 R

Comment: Just add the things you might forgot in the first place as you added the code example which is alredy there (by editing your post)... And I'd say you better add some detail on how you compile your document: TeXstudio settings, bash commands, whatever you do + your `.log`. Apart from that: I really don't know what Qt is doing to render the document but I suspect that in the end it just calls `pdflatex` too.

Comment: @johnson texstudio is just the editor you used to write the file it is unrelated to the tex system you use to process the document. but if you want help with an error **show the error message** that is all the lines in the log file from `!` to `?` in a `{}` code section in the question, so line breaks (which are important in tex error messages) are preserved.

Comment: @johnson And do you get this error with the exact same code (no modifications) taht you posted in your question?

Comment: the undefined control sequence is reported on line 363, and it has something to do with `\languagename`, which doesn't appear in your example.  if i had to guess, there is an "invisible" character in the string `\languagename ,English` in that line; the syntax there looks wrong to me, and i think it likely that what you should have is something like `\languagename{English` -- but you don't show the actual code with the problem in your example, so this is just a guess.

Comment: Unless you give us some code actually producing the error message, nothing useful can be said.